# Error: root when running python script to download from ftp

Tags: python

I am  new to python and recentely upgraded from mysql to mariadb and was  trying to download the data from ftp location to local folder but receiving this error. This script worked on Mysql but is failing on mariadb. I dont understand the error "root" .

```
def all_cam_ids_by_site_id(self,id):
        ret_list =[]
        sql = """SELECT cameras_id FROM carpark_cameras INNER JOIN carpark_roadnames ON carpark_roadnames.id = carpark_cameras.carpark_roadname_id INNER JOIN carpark_locations ON carpark_locations.id = carpark_roadnames.carpark_locations_id INNER JOIN carparks on carparks.id = carpark_locations.carpark_id WHERE carparks.id = "%s" """ % id
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        ret_array = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for retId in ret_array:
            ret_list.append(retId[0])
        return ret_list
```

Ftp Download Script :

```
stats_filename = "/tmp/download_log_%s" % site_id
fp = open(stats_filename, "w")
stats_string = "\n"
fp.write(stats_string)
fp.close()

db_obj = anprint.ExcelDb()
cam_id_list = db_obj.all_cam_ids_by_site_id(site_id)

# Process the cameras for that site
for cam_id in cam_id_list:
    cam_name = db_obj.cam_name_by_id(cam_id)
    print "Downloading %s for %s" % (cam_name, dl_date)
    try:
        myftp = anprint.ftpClient(cam_name)

        dl_count = myftp.downloaddir(dl_date)
        db_obj.log_stats(cam_id, dl_count, dl_date)

        fp = open(stats_filename, "a")
        stats_string = "Downloaded %d entries from %s\n" % (dl_count, cam_name)
        fp.write(stats_string)
        fp.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Error:

```
ERROR:root:No camera with id 272
ERROR:root:No camera with id 271

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ftp_site.py", line 3, in <module>
    import anprint
  File "/usr/local/bin/anprint.py", line 17, in <module>
    hdlr = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 897, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 916, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/anpr_log'

Anprint.py

import mysql.connector as mariadb
import logging
import re
import datetime
import os
import signal
from ftplib import FTP
import sys


LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
LOG_FILENAME = '/tmp/anpr_log'
#logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=LOG_LEVEL)
logger = logging.getLogger("eyetraffic")
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: provide trace of error and where do you use method `all_in_cam_ids_by_site_id` ?

Comment: Thanks Andriy, the  below script is ftp download script and ( the hashed out process the cameras for that site) is where the defintion is called.

Comment: Do you execute that python script with `sudo` command ?

Comment: yes I did with sudo command..

Comment: with sudo these are errors : Downloading GeorgestOUT for 2015-12-23
ERROR:root:No camera with id 272
Downloading GeorgestIN for 2015-12-23
ERROR:root:No camera with id 271

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this output is coming from the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html):

```
ERROR:root:No camera with id 272
ERROR:root:No camera with id 271
```

The `root` in this case refers to the `root` logger, which is the logger that is used when one does not explicitly create a logger. It is unrelated to the root user.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig()
>>> logging.error('I hit an error')
ERROR:root:I hit an error
```

The `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/anpr_log'` error is likely to be unrelated to the the logging output previously mentioned.  Check if that file exists, what the permissions are, and who is the owner.

Comment: I tried to hash out the whole stats log file but the error persists.

Comment: I have provided  the script for the logging in basic config is there any error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is coming from the standard Python logging module. The default format for log messages is

`ERROR_LEVEL:logger_name:message`

So the 'root' your are seeing is the name of the logger, which is the default name given to the default logger set up by the logging module on import.

Your actual error, can be seen on the last line of your Traceback.

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/anpr_log'
```

See the example below. The logging module can also be configured to log/display only messages above a certain error level, by default WARN or more serious.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig()
>>> logging.info("This is just an informational message")
>>> logging.warning("This is a warning message")
WARNING:root:This is a warning message
>>> logging.error("This is an error message")
ERROR:root:This is an error message
```

Despite the mention of 'root' it does not have anything (in this case) to do with your permission error, which is a filesystem permissions issue.

Comment: I  have tried changing the persmission on the file to 777/1777 both the times it got the same error again.

Comment: ERROR:root:No camera with id 272
ERROR:root:No camera with id 271
Downloading GeorgestOUT for 2015-12-23
Downloading GeorgestIN for 2015-12-23